# Program Ends unexpectedly after the function is called

Tags: c++, function, loops, oop, while-loop

[image]
I have to write a program for bank.The classes if you will say I will provide but the problem is here,
My Problem is that in my main program I first call a function called BankProgram(); But there are other statements in the function after the function is being called The below code isnt executed at all

```cpp
cout << "Enter y for opening menu again and n for exiting\t";
    cin >> option;
    while (option != 'y' || option != 'n')
    {
        cout << "Enter right value Please! only y or n: ";
        char option1;
        cin >> option1;
        if (option1 == 'y' || option1 == 'n')
        {
            break;
        }
    }
        
        if (option == 'y')
        {
    
            goto label;
        }
        else if (option == 'n')
        {
            cout << "The program is ending now! ";
        }
```

Although I want to display the menu again for the user to do anything in the bank but the program terminates and exits I dont know why.I think there is a problem with object lifetime but I think that must not be the problem
Any help is appreciated.

This is the AddAccount Class

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class Accounts
{
    vector<int> Account_ID;
    vector<string> AccountType;
    vector<int> Customer_ID;
    vector<int> Account_Balance;
public:
    Accounts();
    void WithDraw(int);
    void Deposit(int,string,int,int);//Also can be named as add Account
    void Balance();
    void DeleteAccount(int);
    int getAccountsNumber();
};
//Definning classes methods
Accounts::Accounts()
{
//no need to initialize vectors.They work perfect without initializing.C++ has done work for it
}
void Accounts::Deposit(int AID,string AT,int CID,int AB)
{
    this->Account_ID.push_back(AID);
    this->AccountType.push_back(AT);
    this->Customer_ID.push_back(CID);
    this->Account_Balance.push_back(AB);

}
void Accounts::WithDraw(int index)
{
    cout << "\nThe Account ID of " << (index + 1) << " person is equal to: "
        << this->Account_ID[index] << endl;

    cout << "\nThe Account Type of " << (index + 1) << " person is equal to: "
        << this->AccountType[index] << endl;

    cout << "\nThe Customer ID of " << (index + 1) << " person is equal to: "
        << this->Customer_ID[index] << endl;

    cout << "\nThe Account Balance of " << (index + 1) << " person is equal to: "
        << this->Account_Balance[index] << endl;

}
void Accounts::DeleteAccount(int index)
{
    Account_ID.erase(Account_ID.begin()+index);
    AccountType.erase(AccountType.begin()+index);
    Customer_ID.erase(Customer_ID.begin()+index);
    Account_Balance.erase(Account_Balance.begin()+index);
    //Displaying that the account is successfully removed from the bank
    cout << "\nThe Account ID of " << (index + 1) << " was successfully removed from the bank";
    cout << "\nThe Account Type of " << (index + 1) <<" was successfully removed from the bank";
    cout << "\nThe Customer ID of " << (index + 1) << " was successfully removed from the bank";
    cout << "\nThe Account Balance of " << (index + 1) << " was successfully removed from the bank";

}
//It will display all the balance in the bank
void Accounts::Balance()
{
    //The static int is not changed on the iteration where ever used in the loop or where ever
    static int sum = 0;//To store the sum of all balance
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Account_Balance.size(); i++)
    {
        sum = sum + Account_Balance[i];
    }
    cout << "The total balance in the bank is equal to : " << sum;
}
int Accounts::getAccountsNumber()
{
    return Account_ID.size();
}
```

This is the Customer Class

```
#pragma once
#include<string>
using namespace std;
#include"Accounts.h"
#include"Manager.h"
class Customer
{
    vector<string> Name;
    vector<int> ID;
public:
    Customer();
    void AddCustomer(string,int);
    void PrintAllCustomersData();
    void DeleteCustomer(int);
    void Print_CustomerDetails(int);
    string getCustomerName(int);
};
void Customer::AddCustomer(string n, int id)
{
    this->Name.push_back(n);
    this->ID.push_back(id);
    cout << "\nThe customer " << n << "with Id: " << id << " was successfully added in the Bank.";
}
void Customer::PrintAllCustomersData()
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ID.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "\nThe ID of " << (i + 1) << "Customer is : " << ID[i] << " and NAME is : " << Name[i];
    }
}
void Customer::DeleteCustomer(int index)
{
    Name.erase(Name.begin() + index);
    ID.erase(ID.begin() + index);
    cout << "\nThe customer with Name : " << Name[index] << " and ID: " << ID[index] << " was successfully deleted\n";
}
void Customer::Print_CustomerDetails(int index)
{
    cout << "The Customer Name is : " << Name[index] << endl;
    cout << "The Id of Customer is : " << ID[index] << endl;
}
string Customer::getCustomerName(int index)
{
    return (Name[index]);
}
```

This is the Manager Class

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class Manager
{
    string Name;
    string Branch;
    int ID;
public:
    void Print_ManagerDetails();
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Manager& M);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, Manager& M);
};
void Manager::Print_ManagerDetails()
{
    cout << "\nThe ID of Manager is : " << ID << endl;
    cout << "\nThe Name of Manager is : " << Name << endl;
    cout << "\nThe Branch of Manager is : " << Branch << endl;
}
istream& operator>>(istream& input, Manager& M) {
    input >> M.ID >> M.Name>>M.Branch;
    return input;
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const Manager& M) {
    output << "\nThe ID of Manager is : " << M.ID<<endl;
    output << "\nThe Name of Manager is : " << M.Name << "\nThe Branch of Manager is : " << M.Branch<<endl;
    return output;
}
```

This is the Bank Class

```
#pragma once
#include"Customer.h"
#include"Accounts.h"
class Bank
{
    Customer* customers_ptr;
    Accounts* Accounts_ptr;
    Manager manager;
public:
    Bank();
    void AddAccount(int,string,int,int);
    void DeleteAccount(int);
    void AddCustomer(string,int);
    void DeleteCustomer(int);
    int GetNoOfAccounts();
    string GetCustomer_Name(int);
};
Bank::Bank()
{
    cout << "\nThe program is in the bank class\n";
}
void Bank::AddAccount(int AID, string AT, int CID, int AB)
{
    Accounts_ptr->Deposit(AID, AT, CID, AB);
}
void Bank::DeleteAccount(int index)
{
    Accounts_ptr->DeleteAccount(index);
}
void Bank::AddCustomer(string name, int ID)
{
    customers_ptr->AddCustomer(name, ID);
}
void Bank::DeleteCustomer(int index)
{
    customers_ptr->DeleteCustomer(index);
}
int Bank::GetNoOfAccounts()
{
    int num=Accounts_ptr->getAccountsNumber();
    return num;
}
string Bank::GetCustomer_Name(int index)
{
    string name = customers_ptr->getCustomerName(index);
    return name;
}
```

This is the main program

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<conio.h>
#include<algorithm>
#include"Bank.h"
#include"Customer.h"
#include"Manager.h"
#include"Accounts.h"
using namespace std;

void BankProgram();


void BankProgram()
{
    Bank b1;
    Accounts A1;
    Manager m1;


    char options;

    cout << "\n\nEnter what you want to do \n1 for entering the managers data,\n2 for showing the managers data "
        << "\n3 for adding a customer in the bank\n4 for adding an account in the bank \n5 for deleting the customer\n"
        << "\n5 for deleting the account\n6 for getting customer name\n7 for getting No. of accounts"
        << "\n8 for seeing all the balance in the bank\nPress 'e' for exit";

    cin >> options;


    switch (options)
    {
    case '1':
    {
        //The manager class data
        cout << "\nEnter the name,ID,Branch Of Manager: ";
        cin >> m1;
        break;
    }
    case '2':
    {
        cout << "\nThe data of Manager is :" << m1;
        break;
    }
    case '3':
    {
        string Cname;
        int CID;
        cout << "\nEnter the name of customer: ";
        cin >> Cname;
        cout << "\nEnter the Customer ID: ";
        cin >> CID;
        b1.AddCustomer(Cname, CID);

        break;
    }
    case '4':
    {
        int AID;
        int CID;
        int AB;
        string AT;
        cout << "\nEnter the name of Account ID: ";
        cin >> AID;
        cout << "\nEnter the name of Customer ID: ";
        cin >> CID;
        cout << "\nEnter the name of Account BALANCE: ";
        cin >> AB;
        cout << "\nEnter the name of Account Type: ";
        cin >> AT;
        b1.AddAccount(AID, AT, CID, AB);

        break;
    }
    case '5':
    {
        int index;
        cout << "\nEnter the customer which you want to delete: ";
        cin >> index;
        b1.DeleteCustomer(index);

        break;
    }
    case '6':
    {
        int index;
        cout << "\nEnter the account which you want to delete: ";
        cin >> index;
        b1.DeleteAccount(index);

        break;
    }
    case '7':
    {
        int cn;
        cout << "\nEnter the customer ID which you want to get name: ";
        cin >> cn;
        b1.GetCustomer_Name(cn);

        break;
    }
    case '8':
    {
        b1.GetNoOfAccounts();

        break;
    }
    case '9':
    {
        A1.Balance();
        break;
    }
    case 'e':
    {
        cout << "The program is ending now: ";

        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        cout << "\n\nEnter right value please: \n";
    }

    }
}


int main()
{


    
//  BankProgram();
    
    
    bool flag = true;
    char option;
label:
    BankProgram();
    cout << "Enter y for opening menu again and n for exiting\t";
    cin >> option;
    while (option != 'y' || option != 'n')
    {
        cout << "Enter right value Please! only y or n: ";
        char option1;
        cin >> option1;
        if (option1 == 'y' || option1 == 'n')
        {
            break;
        }
    }
        
        if (option == 'y')
        {
    
            goto label;
        }
        else if (option == 'n')
        {
            cout << "The program is ending now! ";
        }
    
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218455/discussion-on-question-by-bilal-program-ends-unexpectedly-after-the-function-is).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it turns out to be very simple

```
Bank::Bank()
{
    cout << "\nThe program is in the bank class\n";
}

void Bank::AddAccount(int AID, string AT, int CID, int AB)
{
    Accounts_ptr->Deposit(AID, AT, CID, AB);
}
```

`Accounts_ptr` is an uninitialised pointer, using it results in a program crash. You must give `Accounts_ptr` a value in the `Bank` constructor.

You have the same issue with `customers_ptr`.

Comment: Sir I initialized it with Accounts_ptr = nullptr; in the constructor but it dosent seems to work and I am supposed to use the pointers like this

Comment: @bilal You are supposed to initialise it to point at an `Accounts` object. Something like `Accounts_ptr = new Accounts();`

Comment: If you must use pointers (I don't see why, but you say you must) then you have to make them point at objects. It doesn't happen automatically.

Comment: but can you give me a clue I initilaized it with nullptr isnt it enough

Comment: Because to work with an `Accounts` object the object must exist. `Accounts_ptr = nullptr;` does not make an `Accounts` object.

Comment: Thanks Sir I now came to know.Thanks for the time

Comment: @bilal No problem, glad to help. Next time you have a similar problem, please take the time to describe what you are doing with the program in the question.

Comment: @Sure Sir I will try to study more before posting any question.It was my fault